# Moving changes between commits, to get a clean branch?

Tags: git, version-control

We create new branches for each ticket. The branch is merged into master when the ticket is done. Each ticket branch typically has several commits.

For readability and testing, I try to create commits that:

- are atomic
- focus on only one topic
- do not break the solution

Sometimes I know on beforehand exactly what commits I intend to do in the branch. For example:

1. Create back-end api for visitor registration
2. Refactor visitor categorisation function
3. Create front-end for visitor registration
4. Create simple visitor registration confirmation page

But quite often I discover an opportunity to make an improvement that by topic should belong to a previous commits. Continuing with the example above it might be that I discover that in commit 2 I renamed a variable to "v" when I think that "visitor" would have been a better name.

Now I choose one of two options, both of which I think are bad:
- I create a commit 5 that changes something that I already changed in the commit 2, but does it a little better. I think this option is bad because confuses testing and project history readability.
- I reset commits 2-4 and redo them, now inserting the improvement I realised in hindsight into commit 2 where it belongs. I think this commit is bad because this takes time to do.

I think that the second option produces a superior commit history but it takes time to do.

This leads to my question: Is there any faster way to move this change into commit 2?

I am dreaming about an interface similar to the diff interface in Webstorm (where I can click on changes to either include them or revert them) but that also lets me choose to which commit I want to set the changes.

What solutions are out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these algorithm (active using [`rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)):

- create additional branch starting from second commit and switch to new branch
- add fifth commit into this branch
- apply changes from initial branch (third and fourth commit)
- squash second and fifth commit

In more detail the algorithm described below

---

Let's assume that we have such git log output:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h %s" --graph
* 43e94d8 fourth commit
* 8bfc119 third commit
* d5c9a25 second commit
* e17b227 first commit
```

Then we create new branch from second commit:

```
git branch feature-to-change d5c9a25
git checkout feature-to-change
```

Then create fifth commit into feature-to-change branch and apply third and fourth commit on top of it:

```
# create and commit fifth commit
git log --pretty=format:"%h %s" --grap
* 86660c9 fifth commit
* d5c9a25 second commit
* e17b227 first commit

git rebase feature-to-change feature

git log --pretty=format:"%h %s" --graph
* ee0a502 fourth commit
* 2e0e2c6 third commit
* 86660c9 fifth commit
* d5c9a25 second commit
* e17b227 first commit
```

Now we have commits in appropriate order, but we need to squash second and fifth commit

```
git rebase -i HEAD~4

  pick d5c9a25 second commit
  squash 86660c9 fifth commit
  pick 2e0e2c6 third commit
  pick ee0a502 fourth commit
```

After squashing you will get this history

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h %s" --graph
* 758d85c fourth commit
* 3761310 third commit
* ee739dd second commit
* e17b227 first commit
```

These steps do not take up a lot of time and at the end you get branch `feature-to-change` with pretty commit history

Comment: I won't mark it as a solution yet, as the process posted is more complex than I would want. I will mark the answer as a solution if no simpler answer is posted the next few days. Thank you for a good answer and for taking your time to help!